# how do you disable a text command from another text command in Sublimetext

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm creating a plugin in sublime Text 3, and I've hit a snag that I can't figure out. This is my first using python, and the first time I've done even driven desktop development in over a decade, so hopefully this is just a lack of knowledge on my part.

The plugin I'm writing uses text commands to gather data and then uses that data to call another text command that starts a subprocess than can run for a significant period of time depending on the arguments passed.

the following is some simplified code.

```
    class BlaOneCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit):
            commandArgs = []
            self.view.run_command('run_command', {"args": commandArgs})

    class BlaTwoCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit):
            commandArgs = []
            self.view.run_command('run_command', {"args": commandArgs})

    class BlaThreeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit):
            commandArgs = []
            self.view.run_command('run_command', {"args": commandArgs}) 

    class BlaRunCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit, args):
            self.commandArgs = args
            sublime.set_timeout_async(self.runCommand, 0)

        def runCommand(self):
            proc = ''
            if os.name == 'nt':
                startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
                startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
                proc = subprocess.Popen(self.commandArgs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, startupinfo=startupinfo)
            else:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(self.commandArgs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

            while proc.poll() is None:
                try:
                    data = proc.stdout.readline().decode(encoding='UTF-8')
                    print(data, end="")
                except:
                    return;
```

BlaOne, BlaTwo, & BlaThree are set up in a context menue. and what I need to do is disable some or all of them while the subprocess is running. I know this can be done by overriding the is_enabled method. However I'm struggling with how to tie them all together.

How can I make all the objects aware of each other, so they can enable/disable each other?

Answer (score 0):

After another 5 hours of reading, I figured it out. As I assumed, it was a lack of Python knowledge on my part.

All I needed to do was create a module level variable to use as a flag.